# How to kill a TCP connection using tcpkill utility

Tags: linux, tcp, netstat

I'm trying to kill an ESTABLISHED TCP connection using `tcpkill`.  The connection is an open HTTPS connection.  It appears on netstat as:

```
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:55601         X.X.X.X:https    ESTABLISHED
```

So, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpkill), I enter:

```
$ tcpkill -i eth1 -9 port 443
```

The tcpkill utility outputs:

```
tcpkill: listening on eth1 [port 443]
```

...and then just hangs.  After waiting for about 15 minutes, I'm not sure what's going on here.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem and I was just using the wrong interface (eth0 instead of lo), the answer from Marl helped me a lot https://serverfault.com/a/315728/277736

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For tcpkill to work (i.e., craft a reset packet that has the correct sequence number and source port), there must be traffic. If nothing more is printed then there is no traffic. To verify you could run `tcpdump -i eth1 port 443`.

Answer (score 3):

I had to kill an established connection on which there was no traffic (a debug session on a JVM).

`tcpkill` as explained in @Mark Wagner answer could not do it, however `killcx` 1.0.3 ([link](http://killcx.sourceforge.net/)) did (Ubuntu 10.04).

It is a perl script that has a dependency on a few libraries.

**Edit**

On a connection that could not be killed with `killcx` the combination of both `tcpkill` and `killcx` did it:

Say the connection if from `LOCAL:PORTL`  to `REMOTE:PORTR`

- In a terminal start tcpkill: `tcpkill port PORTL`. Tcpkill will start listening for traffic
- In a second terminal launch killcx:  `killcx REMOTE:PORTR`

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to specify the **local (source) port**, not the remote port, ie.

```
$ sudo netstat -np | grep myclient
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:46844 y.y.y.y:https ESTABLISHED 1234/myclient
$ sudo tcpkill -i eth0 port 46844
tcpkill: listening on eth0 [port 46844]
... [output which shows tcpkill working, once there is traffic] ...
```

So in your case it should be:

```
$ tcpkill -i eth1 -9 port 55601
```